# C# : how to use enum key word?

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following code, The problem is when I'm trying to assign the country to customer, getting error. I need to know how to assign the property that is declared as enum? I will use this in a linq expression, is there any other way to use enum?

```
var customers = new Customer[] {
    new Customer { Name= "Badhon",City=   "Dhaka",Country=Countries.Country.Bangladesh,Order= new Orders[] {
        new Orders { OrderID=1,ProductID=1,Quantity=2,Shipped=false,Month="Jan"}}},
    new Customer {Name = "Tasnuva",City = "Mirpur",Country =Countries .Country .Italy,Order =new Orders[] {
        new Orders { OrderID=2,ProductID=2,Quantity=5,Shipped=false,Month="Feb"}}}
}
```

My `enum` is defined like this:

```
public class  Countries
{
    public enum Country  {Italy,Japan,Bangladesh};

}
```

And `Customer` as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name;
    public string City;
    public Countries Country;
    public Orders[] Order;

    public override string  ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} - City: {1} - Country: {2}", this.Name, this.City, this.Country);
    }

}
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'JoinDemo.Countries.Country' to 'JoinDemo.Countries' D:\Developement\C#-BIT\C# Practice\JoinDemo\JoinDemo\Form1.cs 22 69 JoinDemo

Comment: In case you don't know, `enum`s don't have to be declared inside classes. Actually, that's something quite rare.

Comment: phg: Not *that* rare, but usually they somehow belong to the class, instead of just having a class wrapper around them that does nothing ;)

Comment: One note: If you post code, please make sure you only post *relevant* code. This might be difficult at first, especially when you're still struggling with the basics, but a *wall of code* is something no one really wants to read before understanding your problem. The error message hinted at `Countries` being part of the problem and including the definition of the class you're using is just another good idea, then. And, most importantly: *If you get errors, always include the error message.* While some errors are easy to see for someone experienced the message helps in nearly all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'm really struggling with rules & regulations of stackoverflow.com .Already lost some reputation & the ability to ask new question. I will keep your words in mind.

Comment: I made the correction with enum, now I used a linq query to retrieve data like this: var list= from s in Customers select s; Then tried to set this list to grid like this: datagridview1.datasource=list.ToString(); but not showing any data. add another linke as: datagridview1.datamember= list.ToString(); Showing an run time error like, "Child list for field JoinDemo cannot be created". I did have this kind of problem before while trying to bind data to grid. Can you please help over this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your field in Customer is of type `Countries`, not `Countries.Country`. And you are trying to assign a `Countries.Country` which obviously is incompatible.

An enum is a *type*, just like classes are. You don't need the class around it. You should get rid of the outer class there:

```
public enum Country { Italy,Japan,Bangladesh }
```

and redefine the field in `Customer`:

```
public Country Country;
```

(yes, having a class member with the same name as a type works in C#).

Another issue: You should probably use properties and not fields:

```
public Country Country { get; set; }
```

This will make your life easier down the line (and you can use it just like you did now, until you have read up on the differences).